# Loading one dataset using data from another in Angular $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a messaging service that needs to do the following 1.) Load a messsage from our messages service, get the recipient's ids, and then load the recipients' info from a users service. I've tried both using the messages service callback, and also creating a watcher on the message object, without much success. The service works, but it doesn't assign the result to the $scope correctly. Here's the controller. All of the services are working correctly:

```
function MessageCtrl ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, Messages, Members) { 
    if ($routeParams.mid) {  // Checks for the id of the message in the route. Otherwise, creates a new message.
        $scope.mid = $routeParams.mid;
        $scope.message = Messages.messages({mid: $scope.mid}).query();

        $scope.$watch("message", function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
            if (newVal.data) { 

                $scope.recipients = Members.members({uids: newVal.data[0].uids}).query();
            }
        }, true);

    } else {
        $scope.create = true;
    }

    // Events

    $scope.save = function () { };
    $scope.preview = function () { };
    $scope.send = function () { };  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use `query` is to perform the action in the callback that is passed in query function. In other words`$scope.message` should be assigned in the callback. Also you don't need a $watch. You can call the other service within the callback directly. But to keep it clean please use `deferred`

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q